# How do I tell the typescript compiler to ignore static files.

Tags: typescript

- both frontend/backend written in Typescript.
- frontend is bundled by webpack and imports static assets whose loading is handled by webpack loaders.
- backend code (ran using ts-node) imports some frontend code (types/config).
- Backend cannot not compile pngs.

---

```
 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { �PNG
                                                              ^
 SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

---

I know this could be fixed by moving the frontend's static imports to files that are not imported by backend code, but I wanted to make sure that that was my only option.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use [tsconfig's exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) property to exclude specific files. Is that what you want?

Comment: Can you supply the code in the frontend, which imports the static assets? Is this also the code, which is being reused in the backend?

Comment: @pushkin from what I've tested, the exclude setting is ignored if a file is explicitly imported

Comment: @LukasBach it is `import "../static/image.png";`. I configured webpack to use `file-loader` for pngs, and `ts-loader` for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this would not solve the problem globally, you could test dynamically if you are in frontend code or backend code when using require instead if import.

```
if (isInFrontend) {
  require("../static/image.png");
} else {
  // code is executed from backend, don't import the image and do something else
}
```